# ForEach ID's Group By ID

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to group objects which match it ids to single object one by one.
Explain:
[image: see below]

I don't want to remove duplicate ID's, I want to group objects by ID's. for example: chrome id = 7788 in 3 times. which means chrome has 3 objects (as you know). now i want to add all 3 objects to the one single object. and so on. 
 Anyone have a clue about this ?

Comment: `Group-Object`? Otherwise I think you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Group-Object" cmdlet to bunch the similar processes.

Let's assume you stored the command you're using to generate this output in $x

`$x | Group-Object -Property ID`

This will give you a unique list of ID's, with associated counts of how many processes are in that group.

You can store this in another variable (say, $y, for example) and then be able to call the order by referencing the position in the table you built.

`$y = $x | Group-Object -Property ID`

`$y[0]`

The output will look similar to something like this:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
1 7148                      {@{Id=7148; ProcessName=ApMsgFwd}}
```

Comment: Why you use [-Unique] ? I want to object all matches by one object, but in those object it show's me all process ids.

Comment: With -unique It will remove any duplicate ID's.  From the screenshot you provided, the duplicates are all the exact same.  Is there something else you're looking for?  Are you wanting to preserve the number of lines?  If so, we may need to edit the question and answer to use Group-Object.

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicate ID's, I want to group objects by ID's. for example: chrome id = 7788 in 3 times. which means chrome has 3 objects (as you know). now i want to add all 3 objects to the one single object. and so on

Comment: Updated answer with "Group-Object" instead.  See if this answers your question @Aso  You may want to update your question to more accurately reflect what you're asking for.